# How to display a variable in Powershell HTML email

Tags: html, powershell, email

I have a Powershell email that is formatted HTML and for the most part, it works great. The only piece I cannot get working is how to inject a dynamic date entry into the body of the email.

I have placed the variable I need at the beginning of my script and then added it into the body.
I have attempted to enclose the variable in parenthesis.
I have tried adding to separate lines without any formatting however, nothing I have tried has worked.

Currently this is what I have:

```
<#$body = @" 
<html>
<body>
<img src="cid:image1.png">
<img src="cid:image1a.png">
<img src="cid:banner.png"> 
<img src="cid:image2.jpg">  
<img src="cid:image3.gif">
<img src="cid:example2.png">
</body>
</body>  
</html>  
"@#> 

$dte = (Get-Date).AddDays(7)
$body = @'

HTML formatted content 

$dte

more content

'@

$Log_File = log file location
$users = import-csv import users file and lookup their manager then write to the managers file
$Managers = Import-csv import the managers file
$smtpout = smtpserver
$smtpFrom = sending address
$subject = Read-host 'What is the subject of your email'
$att = @(All the attachments above)

ForEach($Manager in $Managers){

$ToAddress = $Manager.email
$CCAddress = $Manager.manager
$FName = $Manager.first
$LName = $Manager.last

"$(Get-TimeStamp) sending email to $FName $LName ($ToAddress)" | Add-Content $Log_file -PassThru | Write-Output

send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpout -To $ToAddress -Cc $CCAddress -From $smtpFrom -Subject $subject -BodyAsHtml $body -Priority high -Attachments $att
}
```

All I need is a way to get the date function working correctly within the body of the message. So far all I get is the date variable displayed at HTML content. I am assuming it is because the entire body is being treated as a string and formatted in HTML during the sending process.

How can I get this variable working so that it is somehow imported into the body?
Is it even possible?

Comment: Use a double-quoted Here-String for the body instead of single quotes ``$body = @"...$dte..."@`` . See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules)

Comment: That was the issue thanks Theo